# Animation with SDL2 and C

Tags: c, algorithm, animation, sdl-2

I coded drawing a circle using the Bresenham algorithm, it is working well.

But what I want know is how to draw it by using animation, so on the way we can see the circle getting drawn step by step. I know that we will use SDL_Delay function, but I don't have any idea on how to use it.

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#define WINDOW_WIDTH 600

void DrawCircle(SDL_Renderer * renderer, int32_t centreX, int32_t centreY, int32_t radius)
{
   int32_t x = 0;
   int32_t y = radius;
   int32_t m = 2 - 2*radius;

   while (x <= y)
   {
      //  Each of the following renders an octant of the circle
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX + x, centreY - y);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX + x, centreY + y);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX - x, centreY - y);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX - x, centreY + y);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX + y, centreY - x);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX + y, centreY + x);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX - y, centreY - x);
      SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, centreX - y, centreY + x);

    
      if (m > 0)
      {
         --y;
        m = m + 4*(x-y) + 10;
      }
      else 
         m = m + 4*x + 6;
     ++x;
   }
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    SDL_Event event;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;
    SDL_Window *window;

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_WIDTH, 0, &window, &renderer);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 255, 0, 0, 255);

    DrawCircle(renderer, WINDOW_WIDTH/2, WINDOW_WIDTH/2, 100);
    SDL_Delay (200);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);


    while (1) {
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&event) && event.type == SDL_QUIT)
            break;
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: C and C++ are two different languages, Please don't tag multiple different languages, only the one you actually program in.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions. Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Thanks Sir.  about I get the point
Now how the problem should be solve ?

Comment: To animate something, you basically have to draw, erase and redraw (at a new position) in a loop.

Comment: I already draw the circle (or get algorithm to draw it),point per point, now what  I want it is to show it (on a screen) with a delay.. so the first point (pixel) appears, we have delay for 20ms, the second appear and so on ...

Comment: You should do the drawing inside the event loop.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this code

```
for (int i=0; i<=1; i++)
{
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
    SDL_Delay(200);
}
```

inside the function `void DrawCircle (...)`, at the end after if-statement.
So it will show once a point and waiting for 0.2s before show the second
And when we see, it can be like an animation.